# Crontab wget isn't running on digital ocean

Tags: ubuntu, cron, wget, digital-ocean

I've tested a simple echo command to run every minute which it does run, and shows up in my log file, but when I try a cron job to hit the webpage I want it doesn't.

I've tried just using wget, and after some searching, it was recommended to add the path below and use the full wget path (/usr/bin/wget), but still I'm getting nothing.

I'm using digital ocean ubuntu.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$ crontab -l

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

0 3 * * * /usr/bin/wget -O - https://portal.mywebsite.com/index.php/cron/daily_cron >/dev/null 2>&1

0 5 1 * * /usr/bin/wget -O - https://portal.mywebsite.com/index.php/cron/monthly_cron >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Is `crond` running?

Comment: Am I correct that portal.mywebsite.com is hosted on the same server or subnet, were 'cron' is running?
Is https://portal.mywebsite.com resolves to the proper local IP from within the server?
If a public IP is used, the NAT device just won't let the request to go back.
You should just add `<private IP of the instance> portal.mywebsite.com` to `/etc/hosts` to achieve that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: crond is running and that portal.website.com is hosted on the same server

Comment: If you set up the cron jobs without the `>/dev/null 2>&1` - is there anything in the logs?